# Does a new certificate mean importing the entire chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, https, ssl-certificate, keystore

I have a tomcat server on aws configured for https with a certificate set to expire in few days. I understand there's a chain of certificates(starting from root -> Intermediate cert -> actual domain certificate). After generating the .csr file I got the set of crt files(root -> intermediate -> domain cert).

Apart from importing the domain certificate to aws load balancer via portal,

1. Do I need to install all three on tomcat? Or just the domain certificate that was set to expire?
2. When I import the domain certificate into tomcat keystore, will it replace the old certificate? Or is there any concept of  removing the old certificate before replacing with the new one
3. Once imported and the tomcat is restarted, is there generally any downtime where browser/clients give the "Website is not trusted" error?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using certificate on loadbalancer create a certificate in acm and use it on loadbalncer. AWS will not charge you anything for issuing certificate .

Comment: Thanks! Would I still need to import it to the tomcat keystore on my ec2 instance or does AWS manage that if certificate is issued from ACM

Comment: If it is an application level loadbalancer, i.e. it works as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), then you might use a self-signed certificate or no encryption at all. All depends on whether you which to protect the connection between the loadbalancer and your server.